# Colon after Constructor in dart

Tags: constructor, dart, flutter

This code is from flutter gallery and i'm trying to understanding and adapting it. I would know what this syntax means:

```
class DemoItem<T> {
  DemoItem({
    this.valueName,
    this.hintName,
    this.valueSurname,
    this.hintSurname,
    this.builder,
    this.valueToString

  }) : textController = new TextEditingController(text: valueToString(valueName));
```

Especially i would know **what means the colon after the constructor** and if there is a way to define another TextEditingController, in addition to the one already defined.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

The part after `:` is called "initializer list". It is a `,`-separated list of expressions that can access constructor parameters and can assign to instance fields, even `final` instance fields. This is handy to initialize final fields with calculated values.

The initializer list is also used to call other constructors like `: ..., super('foo')`.

Since Dart version 2.0 the initializer list also supports `assert(...)` which is handy to check parameter values.

The initializer list can't read from `this` because the super constructors need to be completed before access to `this` is valid, but it can assign to `this.xxx`.

Pointing out as mentioned in the comments by user693336:

This also means the initializer list is executed before the constructor body. Also the initializer lists of all superclasses are executed before any of the constructor bodies are executed.

Example (copied from https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1394):

```dart
class C {
  final int x;
  final int y;
  C(this.x) : y = x + 1;
}
```

Comment: @lrn thanks good to know that parameters like `this.foo` can now also be accessed in the initializer list.

Comment: That was my experience as well lately this is why I added the hint. I'll have to try again.

Comment: @Remi Thanks for pointing out this answer. Before I submit a question, I depend on SO to provide me with possible answers already provided: it did BUT the colon questions already asked were about C, C++, FORTRAN, etc. None answered the question I asked because they did not address dart. I also object to your removing parts of my post. I get frustrated with SO when it applies a rule blindly. The original question was complete without unnecessary additional prose.

Comment: How does this differ from providing a body for the constructor and initialising variables there?

Comment: It allows you to assign values to final fields. Final fields are alerady sealed when the constructor body is executed (as mentioned in my answer)

Comment: This answer is spot on but I felt it may be improved by distinctly pointing out that the initializer is ran before the constructor body. This is implied in the current answer but is worth stating. This allows for some fields to be calculated or per-initialized before the constructor body is executed.

Answer (score 25):

To elaborate on other answers and to complete the syntax, it is also possible to have a real body for the constructor along with initializer code

```
NonNegativePoint(this.x, this.y) : assert(x >= 0), assert(y >= 0) {
    print('I just made a NonNegativePoint: ($x, $y)');
}
```

^ Here the assertions happen before the execution of the body

Another use case is to assign values to final fields before body executes

```
final num x;
final num y;

Point.fromJson(Map<String, num> json) : x = json['x'], y = json['y'] {
    print('In Point.fromJson(): ($x, $y)'); 
}
```

Comment: in case the assertion fails in the initializer list, will the execution of the constructor be stopped?

Comment: Thank you -- I was looking for how to have a constructor body vs. the colon : constructor code when I found this question.