# How to present an empty view in flutter?

Tags: flutter

How to present an empty view in flutter as Widget.build cannot return null to indicate that there is nothing to render.

Comment: so return an empty  `Containter` or `Material` or similar widget..

Comment: In case you need a placeholder, do not forget there is a placeholder widget : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPe56fezmoo

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

    );
  }
}
```

You can also simply return an empty `Container` and avoid using the `Scaffold` entirely. But this would result in a black screen if this is the only primary widget in you app, you can set the `color` property of the `Container` if you want to prevent the black background.

Example:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white // This is optional
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 416):

For anyone like me who was wondering what is "the correct way" to show an empty widget - official Material codebase uses this:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SizedBox.shrink();
}
```

[`SizedBox.shrink()`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SizedBox/SizedBox.shrink.html) is a widget that is unlike `Container` or `Material` has no background or any decorations whatsoever. It sizes itself to the smallest area possible, if not influenced by parent constraints.

Comment: which basically just returns `SizedBox(width: 0, height: 0)` !

Comment: this is the only answer that doesnt throw an error inside a listview

Comment: Even though SizedBox.shrink is useful, it still takes some space in the screen, I would rather say it is like SizedBox(width: 5, height: 5)

Comment: This wont work if you using Column and Row, it will still count as a col and row item

Comment: @test What do you mean by it will still "count" ?

Answer (score 41):

There are many possible solutions of it. Like

1. ```
   Widget build(context) => SizedBox();
   ```
2. ```
    Widget build(context) => Container();
   ```
3. ```
    Widget build(context) => Scaffold();
   ```

Comment: Returning as scaffold just to prevent returning `null` is not a good solution! Additionally, a container will fill its parent constraints, which can often be an undesired result.

Comment: @jnt I just listed different ways of doing it. The better one is `SizedBox` which is equivalent to `SizedBox.shrink()`.

Comment: `SizedBox()` is technically not the same as `SizedBox.shrink()`, because `SizedBox()` will have its properties width and height set to null.
However, I agree that it will have the same behaviour as `SizedBox.shrink()` if the box does not contain any element

Answer (score 33):

## Performance

Container = 166,173 ms

SizedBox.shrink = 164,523 ms

DIY

```dart
main() async {
  testWidgets('test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget( Container());
    final Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch()..start();
    for (int index = 0; index < 5000000; index += 1) {
      await tester.pump();
    }
    timer.stop();
    debugPrint('Time taken: ${timer.elapsedMilliseconds}ms');
  });
}
```

Comment: If you dont know where to put this code, press double shift and open `widget_test.dart`

Comment: how did you evaluate this time for both the widget. is there a way we can check our Widget time/performance anywhere?

Comment: is there anything faster ?

Answer (score 14):

This may be too late but all of these solutions are not suitable in some scenarios like playing with `PopupMenuItems` or affecting UI rendering!

**Null safety Update**

```dart
  [
    .
    .
    .
    if(condition)...[//Conditionally widget(s) here
      Something(...),
    ],
    .
    .
    .
],
```

The solution is to remove null items before pass to the rendering component:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Text('Title'),
    name != '' 
      ? Text(name) //show name
      : null // just pass a null we will filter it in next line!
  ].where((e) => e != null).toList()// Filter list and make it List again!
)
```

in this way, we can have a lot of null and UI will not affect by any empty `Widget`.

`PopupMenuButton` example ***where we cannot pass SizedBox*** :

```dart
PopupMenuButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.add),
    itemBuilder: (context) => [
        PopupMenuItem(
            child: Row(children:[ Icon(Icons.folder), Text('So something')]),
            value: 'do.something',
        ),
        1 > 2 //⚠️ A false condition
        ? PopupMenuItem(
           child: Row(children: [ Icon(Icons.file_upload), Text('⚠️No way to display ')]),
            'no.way.to.display',
          )
        : null,// ⚠️ Passing null
        PopupMenuItem(
           child: Row(children: [ Icon(Icons.file_upload), Text('Do something else')]),
            'do.something.else',
        )
    ].where((e) => e != null).toList(),//ℹ️ Removing null items  
    onSelected: (item) {}
)
```

And this can be used as API with `extension`:

```
extension NotNulls on List {
  ///Returns items that are not null, for UI Widgets/PopupMenuItems etc.
  notNulls() {
    return where((e) => e != null).toList();
  }
}

//Usage:
PopupMenuButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.add),
    itemBuilder: (context) => [
        PopupMenuItem(
            child: Row(children:[ Icon(Icons.folder), Text('So something')]),
            value: 'do.something',
        ),
        1 > 2 //⚠️ A false condition
        ? PopupMenuItem(
           child: Row(children: [ Icon(Icons.file_upload), Text('⚠️No way to display ')]),
            'no.way.to.display',
          )
        : null,// ⚠️ Passing null
        PopupMenuItem(
           child: Row(children: [ Icon(Icons.file_upload), Text('Do something else')]),
            'do.something.else',
        )
    ].notNulls(),//ℹ️ Removing null items  
    onSelected: (item) {}
)
```

Comment: Someone should performance test this. I imagine filtering nulls out of a short list will perform better than size boxes. As such, this might be a better solution even when sizebox or empty container is considered "good enough".

Answer (score 11):

When a build function returns null, the error message from flutter is :

> Build functions must never return null. To return an empty space that causes the building widget to fill available room, return "new Container()". To return an empty space that takes as little room as possible, return "new Container(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)".

Comment: Yes. If I run app in a null-safety regimen, I face this problem. So, I choose to follow your recommendation.

Answer (score 8):

The recommended widget to show nothing is to use [`SizedBox`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/SizedBox-class.html).

```
SizedBox(
  width: 200.0,
  height: 300.0,
)
```

Comment: What's the reference for this recommendation?

Comment: Took me ages to reply, but SizedBox has been used inside first party widgets like AppBar to show something empty.

Comment: When creating a Container with width and height 0, Android Studio proposes to replace it with a SizedBox with width and height 0 in case you want to show nothing.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was very similar, but I found `Container` and `SizedBox.shrink` still affect the UI (frustratingly).

The best solution I've got is to build it differently using a named constructor and initializer list. An example of these would be:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
    final String name = 'Default';
    final bool hasThing = true;

    MyWidget({this.name});

    MyWidget.withoutThing({this.name}) : hasThing = false;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        //define widgets they have in common here (as many as possible)
        if (hasThing) {
            return Widget(child: Thing(this.name));
        } else {
            return Widget(child: WithoutThing(this.name));
        }
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
Center(child: MyWidget.withoutThing(name: 'Foo'),)//don't show thing
```

or

```
Center(child: MyWidget(name: 'Foo'),)
```

based on your needs.

For more on initializer lists: [Colon after Constructor in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50274605/colon-after-constructor-in-dart)

Comment: What would the `Thing` and `WithoutThing` widgets look like? They're still widgets so they are not really empty and will still render.

Answer (score 2):

Inside `Column` I am using `SizedBox(height: 0.01)`

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    Text('Title'),
    name == ''
    ? SizedBox(height: 0.01) // show nothing
    : Text(name) // show name
  ]
)
```

Comment: you are giving a very small size can't be check but still it will take the space. you can put 0.0 instead 0.01. the question was, how and what is the best best way to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

If this is in a list of children, then how about removing the null entries in the list?

```
  return Column(
    children: <Widget?>[
      Text(heading),
      _detailOrNull(context),  // function returns a Widget?
    ].whereType<Widget>().toList()
  );
```