# flutter firestore contains any query not fetching documents

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have some documents stored under players in firebase and all of them have an id field with num value (e.g. 1, 3 or 25). now I only have 30 players but I'm trying to avoid getting all 30 player when I only need some to avoid unnecessary reads. I have a a list that has all the id of players I want and I'm trying to use arrayContainsAny to fix my problem like:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('players').where("id", arrayContainsAny: widget.selectedPlayer);
```

where widget selected player is list as I said, I also tried using [1, 2] in place of widget.selectedPlayer but all of them returns no documents.

**PS**: I tried using is equal to and it works fine:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('players').where("id", isEqualTo:  27)
```

here is my section of code

```
players = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('players').where("id", arrayContainsAny: widget.selectedPlayer);


return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: players.snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text('Something went wrong');
    }

    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      return Text("Loading");
    }
    var sortedPlayers = sortPlayersByPosition(snapshot.data.docs);
    debugPrint("player docs: " + sortedPlayers.toString());
    return ListView.builder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
      itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length + 1,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        if (index == 0) {
          // return the header
          return playerHeaderRow(header);
        }
        index -= 1;
        if (widget.selectedPlayer.contains(sortedPlayers[index]["id"])) {
          return buildPlayers(sortedPlayers[index]);
        } else {
          // need to return a empty widget here but return null stop the loop when we come to a false case
          // this will create a empty widget : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55796929
          return SizedBox.shrink();
        }
      },
    );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so if you want to use this function ["An in query returns documents where the given field matches any of the comparison values."](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any)

you are suppose to use wherein and not arraycontainsany, I wish they had a doc somewhere for this