# Present an empty view in a Flutter widget to be used in the slivers of a CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter, widget, flutter-sliver, customscrollview

Related question:
[How to present an empty view in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53455358/how-to-present-an-empty-view-in-flutter/53455897)

Like that question, I need to return an empty view from `Widget.build` to indicate that there is nothing to render, but of course cannot return null. The widget will be used in the `slivers` of a `CustomScrollView`.

However, the suggestions from the answers to that question give errors when trying to use them in a Sliver (for example `SizedBox.shrink()`).

It seems that an empty `const SliverToBoxAdapter()` works.

Is this the best way?

Answer (score 0):

The CustomScrollView needs Sliver type widgets.

`SizedBox`, `Container`, `Row`, `Column`, etc are not Sliver types at all.

So you need to convert them using `SliverToBoxAdapter` / `SliverList` / etc

`SliverToBoxAdapter(child: SizedBox.shrink())` seems the more explicit to me yeah