# How to know which widget is expensive to use in terms of space and time to build?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, android-studio, dart

As we All Know Many widget can do the job for us for single task.

Example -  We need a square Box to show in Flutter App we can achieve this with multiple widget

1. Container
2. SizedBox
3. DecoratedBox
4. ConstrainedBox
5. Elevated Button

And many more widget to perform the same task. now the question comes which is more efficient way to do the job in terms of Time and Space?

Comment: If `SizedBox` is enough, no need to shift to Container. It totally  depends on what exactly you are trying to build.

Comment: That is what i want to know. how you figure out SizedBox is good instead Container. what are the parameter on which basis you came to decide it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of these widgets at your own discretion. The golden rule applies here:

> The more functional a widget is, the more resources are spent to build/draw it.

However, we should not forget that such minimization has a serious adversary - the programmer's time which will be spent on `Wrap with...` by necessary widgets. The same cannot be said for `Container`, which contains most of the parameters.

Comment: According to your answer We should consider the no. of parameters . if the no. is large then the widget will be expensive. I don't agree with this. 

Let me share the widget taken time to build if we just need the to show empty space. 
Container = 166,173 ms
SizedBox.shrink = 164,523 ms

Second example : 
Card(
clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
) - Expensive Widget

Second Ex:

Card(
clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
) - Less Expensive

after using both i got to know second was less expensive than above. I hope we should have a way to find out the every Widget performance (time/space).

Comment: And what methodology did you use to take these measurements?

Comment: Overall, even if we see about 100 containers on the screen, it will have a very minimal impact on performance.
In this case, better performance is facilitated by `const`. Also, note that `SizedBox()` is a const constructor but `Container()` is not. The first one allows the compiler to create more efficient code.

Comment: I got to know that time measurements by Testing the Widget. here is the reference when this question strike me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67047730/6830613