# Colon : in Dart constructor syntax

Tags: dart, flutter

```dart
class X extends Y {
  X(int a, int b) : super(a,b);
}
```

Can someone give me an explanation about the syntax meaning of the colon `:`?

Comment: see https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializer-list and https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors

Comment: the : is like calling Constructor(){// what ever you want}

Comment: @user8773560 No, that is precisely what it is not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Colon after Constructor in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50274605/colon-after-constructor-in-dart)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This feature in **Dart** is called "initializer list".
It allows you to initialize fields of your class, make *assertions* and call the super constructor.

This means that it is not the same as the constructor body. As I said, you can only *initialize* variables and **only access *`static`* members**. You cannot call any (non-static) methods.

The benefit is that you can also initialize **`final`** variables, which you *cannot* do in the constructor body. You also have access to all *parameters that are passed to the constructor*, which you do not have when initializing the parameters directly in the parentheses.
Additionally, you can use class fields on the left-hand of an assignment with the same name as a parameter on the right-hand side that refers to a parameter. Dart will automatically use the class field on the left-hand side.
Here is an example:

```dart
class X {
  final int number;

  X(number) : number = number ?? 0;
}
```

The code above assigns the parameter named `number` to the *`final`* field `this.number` if it is non-null and otherwise it assigns `0`. This means that the left-hand `number` of the assignment actually refers to `this.number`. Now, you can even make an assertion that will never fail (and is redundant because of that, but I want to explain how everything works together):

```dart
class X {
  final int number;

  X(number): number = number ?? 0, assert(number != null);
}
```

[Learn more](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializer-list).

Answer (score 1):

It's ok to access non static member in initializer list.

```dart
class Point {
  num x, y;

  Point(this.x, this.y);
  Point.origin(): this.x = 10, this.y = 10;
}

main() {
  Point p = Point.origin();
  print(p.x); // 10
}
```

Comment: I explained it in my answer: you can initialize variables but cannot call non-static methods.