# How do I use `this` in constructors?

Tags: python, flutter, dart

In python if I call a method on an object a reference to the object itself is put into the function. I want to have a similar behaviour in dart but I can't find out how to get the same behaviour as in python with the `self` variable.
I basicaly want to implement a behaviour like this:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.child = Child(self)

class Child:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
```

In dart I would expect it to look somehow like this:

```
class Parent {
  final Child child;

  Parent() : this.child = Child(this);
}

class Child {
  final Parent parent;

  Child(parent) : this.parent = parent;
}
```

but putting the this keyword into the parentheses in dart causes an error.
The error message is:

```
Error compiling to JavaScript:
main.dart:4:33:
Error: Can't access 'this' in a field initializer.
  Parent() : this.child = Child(this);
                                ^^^^
Error: Compilation failed.
```

How can I implement the behaviour demonstrated in the python code in dart?

Comment: *"putting the this keyword into the parentheses in dart causes an error"* What error? Please show the full error message.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot access `this` in neither the constructor head nor in the initializer list (learn more about what that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56037596/6509751)).

If you want to do it, you will have to initialize your `child` variable in the constructor **body**:

```dart
class Parent {
  Parent() {
    child = Child(this);
  }

  Child child; // Cannot be final.
}
```