# How do I use non-constant values for optional parameters

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a custom class for my `FlutButton` widget and when I try to specify the color property with square brackets I get this error:

```
The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.
```

```
class CustomFlatButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final Color color;
  final Color textColor;
  CustomFlatButton({
    this.text='Default sign in text', 
    this.color = Colors.white70, 
    this.textColor = Colors.grey[900] // this is what is causing the error [900]
  });
```

Is there a way to fix this without converting my widget into a stateful one?

In advance, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/61956960/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **initializer list** to initialize your final instance fields with non-constant values:

```dart
class CustomFlatButton extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomFlatButton({
    this.text='Default sign in text', 
    this.color = Colors.white70, 
    Color textColor,
  }) : textColor = textColor ?? Colors.grey[900];
  
  final String text;
  final Color color;
  final Color textColor;
}
```

In this case, the left-hand of the `textColor = textColor ?? Colors.grey[900]` assignment corresponds to `this.textColor` and the right-hand `textColor` is referring to the constructor parameter. If no value is passed to the constructor, a default value is used using the `??` operator.

---

You can [learn more about the initializer list here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56037596/6509751).
And you can [learn more about the `??` operator here](https://medium.com/@thinkdigitalsoftware/null-aware-operators-in-dart-53ffb8ae80bb).

Comment: Very helpful, much appreciated.