# What does a colon mean in the dart constructor?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm the developers flutter.

```
InheritedCounter({
Key key,
@required this.counterState,
@required this.child
}) : assert(counterState != null), super(key: key, child: child);
```

What does a colon (:) mean in the dart constructor?
I think it's the same as the code below, right?

```
InheritedCounter({
Key key,
@required this.counterState,
@required this.child
}) {
   assert(counterState != null);
   super(key: key, child: child);
}
```

I wonder if colons are just for abbreviation or something else.

Comment: You can find it : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50274605/colon-after-constructor-in-dart

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Thanks to you, I was able to find the exact information.

Comment: That's right. That question is the same as mine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is an **initializer**.
It accepts a comma-separated list of expressions that initialize fields with arguments.

Sometimes we must call super constructors when initializing
Note: that super(...) must always be the last call in the initializer.

If we needed to add more complex guards (than types) against a malformed robot, we can use assert.