# What's mean colon inside a dart class?

Tags: dart, syntax

I'm trying understand what's the mean of this two final lines of code, on colons... It's a syntax question.
I'm following [this](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Flutter/blob/master/example/lib/data/model/diet_plan.dart) github example and I have this doubt on my head.
Can someone help me with this?.

```
class DietPlan extends ParseObject implements ParseCloneable {
  DietPlan() : super(keyDietPlan);
  DietPlan.clone() : this();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Colon after Constructor in dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50274605/colon-after-constructor-in-dart)

Answer (score 1):

The part after : is called "initializer list. 
It is a list of expressions that can access constructor parameters and can assign to instance fields, even final instance fields.

The first colon, i.e. `DietPlan() : super(keyDietPlan);` means that you are calling the super constructor, constructor of ParseCloneable in this case.
This is a core OOP concept, you can extend or implement one class to another and you must call the superclass constructor if you do so. This is just a style of doing the same in Dart.

The second colon works in similar way, to understand that you need to understand what is cloning of objects,
Object cloning refers to creation of exact copy of an object. It creates a new instance of the class of current object and initializes all its fields with exactly the contents of the corresponding fields of this object.
This is whats happening on the second line.