# Flutter, what is the ":"?

Tags: dart

```
enum ListStatus { loading, success, failure }

class ListState extends Equatable {
  const ListState._({
    this.status = ListStatus.loading,
    this.items = const <Item>[],
  });

  const ListState.loading() : this._();

  const ListState.success(List<Item> items)
      : this._(status: ListStatus.success, items: items);

  const ListState.failure() : this._(status: ListStatus.failure);

  final ListStatus status;
  final List<Item> items;

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [status, items];
}
```

1 what is the "._" in the

```
ListState._({...})   ?
```

2 What are the ":" stuck next to those functions? When is it used?

Comment: Colon after constructor is called `initializer list` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50274605/colon-after-constructor-in-dart

Comment: Highly recommend you read the Language Tour at the dart.dev site: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dart
ListState._({...})
```

This is a private named constructor that means you can't instantiate this class object from outside the current library.

---

```dart
const ListState.loading() : this._();
```

This is also a named constructor (not private though) and here `this._())` is simply delegating the call to the private named constructor.

Comment: So what you mean is that ListState.loading and ListState.success in the code above are not basic functions, but constructor functions of this class?

Comment: Yes, `ListState.loading` is a named constructor: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#constructors